# The curl function/operator outputs a scalar in $2$D but a vector in higher dimensions...right?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, vectors, curl

It just seemed a bit strange to me that the type of output (scalar or vector) of something can depend on how many dimensions you're working with. The curl of a vector field on $2$-space is a scalar, while the curl of a vector field on $3$-space (or higher, if the idea of curl exists in higher dimensions) is a vector. Is this correct, and if so, should I be finding it weird? Or is it normal?

Comment: The curl of a vector field in $n$-dimensional space has $n(n-1)/2$ components. When $n=2$, that's $1$ component, the same as a scalar. When $n=3$, it's $3$ components, the same as a vector. In higher dimensions, it matches neither scalars nor vectors. (The "real" story is that the curl of a differential $1$-form is a differential $2$-form, namely the exterior derivative of the $1$-form, but that story seems to be beyond the level of this question. Another version of the real story is that the curl of a vector field is a skew-symmetric tensor field.)

Comment: @AndreasBlass Thank you very much! That is infinitely interesting, and despite the topics being out of my reach you explained things very clearly! I didn't notice that it has $n(n-1)/2$ components but thinking of that leads to the answer to my question very naturally. I'll look into all the other things you mentioned as well. Thank you again!